# How do I create a unit test in dart only riverpod 2.0?

Tags: dart, riverpod

How do I create a unit test for my setState method? This is of course a trivial example but I will have more complicated examples. I need most of my business logic in dart only.

```
class TodoItem {
  final String id;
  TodoItem({required this.id});
}

@riverpod
class TodoItems extends _$TodoItems {
  @override
  List<TodoItem> build() => [];
  void setState(List<TodoItem> newState) => state = newState;
}
```

Comment: There's a whole section on testing riverpod in "dart-mode" in the official documentation, and there are some third-party docs.  Do you have a specific question about a particular strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is described in the Riverpod documentation.  You create a ProviderContainer, then you use the read and listen methods on that container to simulate ref.read and ref.watch/listen.  For example, you can use something like `container.read(todoItemsProvider.notifier).setState('thing')` and then check if `container.read(todoItemsProvider)` is `thing`.  You can also add listens to make sure it is notifying.

If your provider depends on other providers, you can isolate them by using overrides in your ProviderContainer constructor to mock out the dependencies. Thus, you can test as little or as much of the network of providers as you wish.

## Edit

The simplest example (keeping individual tests clean)

```
void main() {
  final container = ProviderContainer();

  tearDown(() => addTearDown(container.dispose));

  test('State is being set', () {
    var newState = [TodoItem(id: '1')];
    container.read(todoItemsProvider.notifier).setState(newState);
    var stateInProvider = container.read(todoItemsProvider);

    expect(stateInProvider.length, 1);
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks @RandalSchwartz, I couldn't seem to work out how to achieve the above after looking at the documentation.  The container.read(todoItemsProvider.notifier) & container.read(todoItemsProvider) was the key confusion as they both return different types of objects.

Comment: Yes, one is the notifier, on which you call methods to mutate the state, and the other is the state itself.

Comment: also, the listener isn't really required to test the values so it can be much more simple than the example in the docs.  As you say in your comment we can just read the 'thing' before and afterwards.

Comment: You'll *want* a listener though if you want to test that the provider is properly emitting.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be testing that the riverpod generated code is working properly?  I can't think of a scenario where the provider wouldn't emit properly.

Comment: You may be testing adding an item to a state that has a list, to make sure you didn't just write state.add(item) but rather state = [...state, item].